# The igxprd32 display driver has stopped working normally

Tags: crash, bsod, windows-xp

I have a 32-bit WinXP machine with NO GPU, and 4GB of RAM. Recently, I started playing Spiral Knights, which caused my computer to BSOD once every couple hours.

Microsoft suggested updating my USB drivers, which I did; still got BSODs occasionally.

Curious, I decided it was video-card related, and decided to:

- Run SK with "low" graphics details
- Run SK with SK's "compatibility mode" for graphics
- Run SK at a lower refresh rate
- Update my graphics chip drivers from Intel

All of this only resulted in *more* crashes. Now, I get the usual error:

`The igxprd32 display driver has stopped working normally ...`

This happens randomly (spanning from every few minutes to every couple of hours), and makes my computer quite unusable -- it won't even shut down properly afterwards.

What can I do to fix this? It seems to be only localized to my home computer. I'm running SK through Steam, if that matters, and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything from Java to SK itself.

For anyone curious, my display adapter shows as `Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family`, and the driver version is the latest according to Intel's website.

Comment: Assuming your PC meets the minimum requirements (and it does), the below refresh/upgrade routine is likely to address most known problems in one shot. Please do the following steps in the exact order listed:

    Uninstall Spiral Knights (remove game data from steam).
    Install the latest video drivers for your video card (from intel's website, just to be sure).  Run Windows update and look for graphics driver updates.
    Download the latest Java.
    
    (Re)install Spiral Knights, then let us know your findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy a GPU.

Seriously.

Your problem is with your combination of game + graphics drivers for your graphics card (albeit an integrated graphics card). Swapping it for a different graphics card (in this case, a GPU) should solve the problem.

They're pretty cheap these days too. You can get one for around $100.

Answer (score 2):

This [thread](http://communities.intel.com/thread/12640) suggests that you should roll-back your video driver to version 6.14.10.4926 A06.

If this does not apply to your computer, try any other older (or newer) versions of the driver for your computer, as this seems to be a driver problem.

(For future comments, it would help to know the make of your computer.)

Comment: I reviewed that link before posting. It talks about laptop drivers. I have a desktop Inspiron 530.

Comment: The display driver works with the video card, for whatever computer model. So it may be worthwhile to try this solution.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it if G Koe's solution is insufficient.

Comment: Maybe you can post a link to the drivers. I don't think laptop drivers will work on a desktop. I get the error "This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software. Setup will now exit."

Comment: I suggest first using the [Intel Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect?iid=dc_iduu) to see if you have the latest versions for all Intel devices.

Comment: Tried that already and I have the latest drivers.

Comment: Then an older driver is needed. For XP then for example the 5026 driver [is here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=17353&ProdId=2877&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%20XP%20%20Professional*&DownloadType=Drivers). This [google query](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=%22Intel%C2%AE+Graphics+Media+Accelerator+Driver+%22+%22G31+Express%22+XP+driver+site%3Adownloadcenter.intel.com&oq=%22Intel%C2%AE+Graphics+Media+Accelerator+Driver+%22+%22G31+Express%22+XP+driver+site%3Adownloadcenter.intel.com) can maybe find you some more.

Comment: I think you're guessing. I've tried already a couple of different drivers from Intel, without any improvement.

Comment: Of course I'm guessing, since I have never encountered this error myself. If this bug is in all versions of the driver, older and current, then your problem has no solution with your current hardware. The only direction I can see is to change hardware, moving to either a new computer or a new GPU (as suggested by @ashes999). I absolutely *don't* advocate investing in an old computer. If you are into gaming, I suggest getting a computer with a good GPU, as onboard video is always problematical for games.

Comment: This is a sad moment. My computer is less than four years old, and it's already being considered obsolete! Maybe I should just ditch SK then, since it's the only game that gives me problems.

Comment: Avoiding games that trigger this bug in the video driver is of course one possible solution. With the new hardware technologies expected within the coming months, waiting will get you a much better computer.

Answer (score 2):

This bug is an implementation problem in the Intel video drivers. Unfortunately (other than checking to make sure you have the latest edition of those drivers), there is very little you as an end-user can do about this.

If you have a gaming platform that is more recent, you may find that drivers for later versions of Windows are more stable, so if you can play this game on Windows7 or on a different machine with a different graphics card you may have more luck.

Other than that, keep your system up to date and make sure you have the latest drivers, but there's not much more you can do, short of writing an angry letter to Intel.

Comment: Nice answer, but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: My point was that there isn't a solution to your problem, short of waiting for better drivers to come out or using a different machine.

Comment: Again, nice, but with 50 rep on the line, that's not good enough for me :)

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: As I said, the driver is broken. If there is a newer driver available you can use that, otherwise your best bet is to file a bug report at Intel and wait for them to fix it. There is no way for normal users to repair buggy driver code - sadly that's just life. Alternatively you could buy a different graphics card and plug it in with its drivers, or you could play on a different machine. If the game lets you turn shaders down or off you might manage to avoid the bug in the driver that's causing the crash, but that's really a stop-gap measure and not a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your PC meets the minimum requirements (and it does), the below refresh/upgrade routine is likely to address most known problems in one shot.

Please do the following steps in the exact order listed:

1. Uninstall Spiral Knights (remove game data from steam).
2. Install the latest video drivers for your video card (from intel's website, just to be sure).
3. Run Windows update and look for graphics driver updates.
4. Remove all OLDER VERSIONS of the Java Runtime environment*
5. Download the latest Java.
6. (Re)install Spiral Knights, then let us know your findings.

*[Why should I remove older versions of Java from my system?](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml)
http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml

(From Oracle on Java.com)
The latest version of Java is always the recommended version as it contains feature updates, vulnerability fixes and performance improvements to previous versions. You can confirm that you have the latest version by visiting the Java Verification page.
Over time, you may have installed multiple versions of Java to run available Java content. In the past, each Java update was installed in separate directories on your system. However, Java updates are now installed in a single directory.

Should I remove older versions of Java?
We highly recommend users remove all older versions of Java from your system.
Keeping old and unsupported versions of Java on your system presents a serious security risk.
Removing older versions of Java from your system ensures that Java applications will run with the most up-to-date security and performance improvements on your system.

How can I remove older versions of Java?
You can safely remove older versions of Java from your system by following the instructions on Java uninstallation instructions for Windows page.

===========================================================================
As a last resort, (via the open GL settings in my comment) **Disable vertical sync for open GL**:
On Microsoft Windows XP:

Access the OpenGL 3D settings here:
Start » Control Panel » Display (or Appearance and Themes » Display) » Settings » Advanced » Intel® Extreme Graphics, Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator Driver, or Intel(R) Graphics and Media Control Panel tab »
Graphics Properties... button » select Advanced Mode (if prompted to select an application mode) » select OpenGL or 3D Settings (or 3D » enable Custom Settings).
To disable vsync on older Intel® graphics products, set Asynchronous Flip to On and click Apply.

**With newer Intel graphics products, set Vertical Sync to No and click Apply.**

Comment: How exactly do I configure SK to use the latest installed JRE? I have three JDKs installed.

Comment: Uninstall ALL of them, and go get the latest one from http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

Comment: Whoa, uninstall every version of Java? That's a little hardcore. Maybe you can update your steps accordingly.

Comment: Yes, unless you have something that is TOTALLY dependent upon a specific version of the Java Runtime Environment.  Please see edits above.

Comment: Done. When I get a couple of hours, I'll see if it still crashes. FYI, that link you sent downloaded Java 6u1; I had the SDK for 7u3 previously downloaded, so I ended up installing both. Weird.

Comment: I am very sad to report that it still crashes. Cheers dude.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas? +1 for effort

Comment: Yep, couple obscure things to try.  Spiral Knights uses Open gl, and the open gl support on the g33/g31 is iffy.  Try fiddling with the open gl settings listed here: http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-030506.htm to see if you can

Comment: Also, I found this to be quite interesting: (from spiral knights guide) If your game or computer crashes after you have been logged into the game for a while, it is possible your computer is overheating or high RAM usage. Try these suggestions:
Make sure your computer is dust free.
Use a fan or cooling mat to keep your computer's temperature in check.
*Restart Spiral Knights after each time you go back to Haven after exploring the Clockworks.*

Comment: Thanks. My computer is pretty cool (I already have temperature monitoring), and I have a lot of free ram, but I'll check. Cheers dude.